# ADODB.RecordSet assigning value from objects in VB.NET performs badly

Tags: .net, ado, adodb

We need to assign a ADODB.RecordSet from our .NET class objects and I am not sure if I am doing it right. Let's say I have a List called orderList which consists of objects of class `Order`, and I need to generate a RecordSet from this list (I have adodb as reference). My code looks like this:

```
Dim rs As Recordset = New Recordset
rs.Fields.Append("ID", DataTypeEnum.adInteger)
rs.Fields.Append("Sender", DataTypeEnum.adBSTR)
rs.Fields.Append("Receiver", DataTypeEnum.adBSTR)
...
rs.Open()

For Each o In orderList
    rs.AddNew()
    rs.Fields("ID").Value = o.ID
    rs.Fields("Sender").Value = o.Sender
    rs.Fields("Receiver").Value = o.Receiver
    ...
Next
```

In my test, when the list has 10000 objects, it takes relatively longt ime: over 3 seconds. This is slow since the number of orders could be as even over a million. I doubt I am using the `RecordSet` properly because as far as I learned the `RecordSet` normally perform direct connection to a table. It doesn't feel right to assign the records one by one. But this is the only way I can come up with (and some link suggests this. Although it doesn't mention about the performance there). We have our own Data Access Layer library and most of the target objects exist in the memory all the time, that's why we don't want to use RecordSet directly to database.

So my question is, how should I modify my code to make it run fast? The "source" doesn't necessarily need to be a `List`. It can be any .NET type. But the target is I must have a `RecordSet` object since that's the input requirement from another component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I use the field reference to improve the performance. In my original code, at least one thing that can be improved is, such sentense `rs.Fields("ID").Value = o.ID` always performs a lookup which consumes some time. @nunzabar suggests to use integer index and I think it makes sense. Something like `rs.Fields(0).Value = o.ID` However, at least in my test it didn't bring any improvement. I then assign the field reference before the loop:

```
Dim f1 As ADODB.Field = rs.Fields.Item("ID")
Dim f2 As ADODB.Field = rs.Fields.Item("Sender")
....
For Each o In orderList
    rs.AddNew()
    f1.Value = o.ID
    f2.Value = o.Sender
    ...
Next
```

This indeed saves some time (about half of the time).

Although I am still not sure whether this is the optimal way of using it, this is so far the best that I can get. Currently for 50,000 records it takes about 6 seconds to perform the Recordset assignment. Not really super fast, so we have to limit the max number of records the user can get.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any shortcuts; I use similar code in one of my projects.  However, I'm fairly certain it will run faster if you reference your fields via index instead of name in the For loop.

Try this and see if you get a performance boost:

```
For Each o In orderList
    rs.AddNew()
    rs.Fields(0).Value = o.ID
    rs.Fields(1).Value = o.Sender
    rs.Fields(2).Value = o.Receiver
    ...
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In fact in my test using integer index won't improve the performance, the time consumed is almost the same. However, if I use a field reference, it improves the performance, in my case it saves about half time. This is how I do it: before For Each loop, I declare Dim f1 As ADODB.Field = rs.Fields.Item("ID"), Dim f2 As ADODB.Field = rs.Fields.Item("Sender"), and inside the loop, I can use these references like f1.value = o.ID f2.value = o.Sender.

Comment: Nice! You may want to post that as an update to you question, or as an answer, so it gets better visibility.